# Do I need to stop all the jobs after re-compiling a jar file used in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, jar, compilation

My question is that supposed that I am making changes in one of the jar file used in the MapReduce process, if I want to re-compile this jar and make the updated jar to work, do I have to stop all the hadoop services first, then re-compile and restart all the services ? If so, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do this regularly. Just recompile the jar and run a new job.